# Log4net : Rolling file on utc date rather than server date

Tags: configuration, log4net

Is there a way to make log4net roll over the file on utc time rather than server time? Right now my file stores logs in utc time. But it rolls over, i.e. creates a new file for each day on server time. The server is on Pacific time, so what happens is that yesterdays file has the first 8 hours of logs from todays file.

E.g. File for Nov-10 has logs until 07:59:59 am of Nov-11.

How do I make log4net roll over the file depending upon utc time?

Comment: About which appender are you talking? RollingFileAppender?

Comment: Duplicated by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229232/log4net-rolling-file-on-utc-date-rather-than-server-date

Answer (score 0):

Extend one of the existing Appenders and reimplement the code that does the reolling over. Shouldn't be too hard.